# PHP Loop for Year Dropdown

Tags: php

I am trying to create a HTML select input based on months/years and I am not sure the best approach for it.

While creating a standard loop of years was the first place I started, I wasn't sure how to get the last days of each of the month/years in order to create the values.

Is there any built in PHP functions that can accomplish something close to what I am looking for?

Logic:

- Must be able to provide a starting year (ex. 2014).
- Must start at the starting year and go 1 year past the current year (ex. If Start = 2014, it will show 2014, 2015, 2016.
- The value of the option must be the last day of the month in date format (ex. `<option value="01/31/2015">January 2015</option>`

Output:

```
<select class="s2 span4" name="desiredCompletion" placeholder="Select a Desired Completion Date">
  <optgroup label="2016">
     <option value="01/31/2016">Janurary 2016</option>
     <option value="02/28/2016">Feburary 2016</option>
     <option value="03/31/2016">March 2016</option>
     ...
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="2015">
     <option value="01/31/2015">Janurary 2015</option>
     <option value="02/28/2015">Feburary 2015</option>
     <option value="03/31/2015">March 2015</option>
     ...
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="2014">
     <option value="01/31/2014">Janurary 2014</option>
     <option value="02/28/2014">Feburary 2014</option>
     <option value="03/31/2014">March 2014</option>
     ...
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please, show some effort / attempts / code before initiating a question.  That would provide a decent starting point on which we can extend the conversation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function should do:

```
function createYearSelect($from) {
    // open select
    echo "<select class=\"s2 span4\" name=\"desiredCompletion\" placeholder=\"Select a Desired Completion Date\">";

    // for each year from the one specified to the one after current
    foreach(range($from, date('Y') + 1) as $year) {
        // open optgroup for year
        echo "<optgroup label=\"$year\">";

        // foreach month
        foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {
            // timestamp of first day
            $time = strtotime("$year-$month-01");

            // create option with date() formatting
            echo "<option value=\"".date("m/t/Y", $time)."\">".date("F Y", $time)."</option>";
        }

        // close optgroup for year
        echo "</optgroup>";
    }

    // close select
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: This seems to do just what I need. How difficult is it to change the order if I wanted it to have the earliest year on the bottom? You don't need to change the answer, just looking for the spot I can change it.

Comment: To reverse the year order, just replace `range($from, date('Y') + 1)` with `range(date('Y') + 1, $from, -1)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit more elegant way

```
foreach(range(2014, 2015) as $year){
    foreach(range(1, 12) as $month){
        echo date('Y.m.d', strtotime('Last day of ' . date('F', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-01')) . $year)) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

This outputs the list of the last days of months for the years in specified range.

```
2014.01.31
2014.02.28
2014.03.31
2014.04.30
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `DateTime` class you can create dates using natural language.

Eg,

```
$date = new DateTime("-1 Year"); 
echo $date->format('F Y'); // Prints 'December 2014'
```

You can use a decrementing `for` loop to create many dates going back in time.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the function below which gives the total number of days in a month

`date("t")`;

Further details are available at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php