# Select Dynamic value from Dropdown using PHP

Tags: php, select

How can I Populate a Select DropDown with last year value (2016) as selected default?

```html
<?php
 $last_year = date ("Y");
 print "<select>";
 for( $i = 2004; $i <= $last_year; $i++ ) {
  echo "<option selected=\"$last_year\" value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
 };
 print "</select>";
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I found similar requirement and solution in below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206981/php-loop-for-year-dropdown

Comment: Sidenote: `echo` uses one less character then `print` (more strain on your fingers). You can see the differences in this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo - If `print` what you really want to use, the more power to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <?php
    $last_year = date ("Y");
    print "<select>";
    for( $i = 2004; $i <= $last_year; $i++ ) {
        $selected = ($last_year == $i) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        echo "<option $selected value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
    }
    print "</select>";
    ?>
```

If I got you right, then this should work for you. What you did was to select every year instead of just the last one.

Comment: Just for reference, you can edit deleted answers and then undelete them, rather than answering twice

Comment: Thanks, but ikr, accidently clicked the wrong button. Me brainfart ^.^

Comment: LOL, ok no problem

Comment: your line code, return FALSE

Comment: Fixed it, works now

Comment: in Firefox 47.0 not work, in chrome 52.0... work :)

Comment: I have FF47.0.1 and it works. There is no reason why is shouldnt work on any browser ^^

Comment: My code not work in Firefox with refresh F5 or button refresh because my page is loaded from cache, not from server. It works only with CTRL+F5 or my code is `echo '<select autocomplete="off">';`

Answer (score 1):

doing a comparison in the loop like this:

```
for( $i = 2004; $i <= $last_year; $i++ ) {
    if($i == $last_year){
        $sel = 'selected=selected';
    } else {
        $sel = '';
    }
    echo "<option value='$i' $sel>$i</option>\n";
};
```

Comment: You should not assign null if it is not the right year, just do an empty string to prevent errors

Comment: I've done it this way for years without any issues.

Comment: @Dave In else part edit that "null" value to some other value, for safe code handling, I accept that else condition will not be assigned but for code quality and avoid breaking in unconditional scenario, assign empty value. Thanks

Comment: OK I've emptied it.

Comment: Another, shorter way, would be to use short if condition or setting the $sel to an empty string right before the if statement

Comment: Not work, i tested with `print_r ($sel);` and return selected=selected and `print_r($i);` return 2017

Comment: if your after 2016 you could hard code it:  if($i == '2016'){

Comment: I changed `$sel = 'selected=selected';` with `$sel = 'selected=\"selected\"';` and function in chrome v.52.0.. and in Firefox 47.0 not work :)

Comment: Basically this is the same code as I posted, so it should work exactly the same